# Best architecture for AngularJS based MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor, model-view-controller

Client side complexity will increase by adding angular mechanisms such as client side modules, controllers and models!

in the other hand by developing MVC .Net web applications we have a good pattern so supports a lot of features and specially increasing re-useability, which we generally miss that in angular based web applications
angular pages with MVC apps causes duplicate codes in server side and client side. i don't know any way to avoid duplicate models and also strongly-typed models!

ok, i know implementing strongly typed model mechanism which models comes from server side is hard. but at least i want to prevent duplicate code with some existing techniques or NEW techniques!

**First:** are there existing approach? i did not find after lots of searching.

Scenario:
I'm developing a Plugin-Based MVC application which has core and some plugins that they have been implemented on MVC atchitecture. so all of them have own controllers and also own actions and views. The starting page or the so called "Main Application" which starts at first of core staring and contains my plugins contents within, is a SPA(Single Page Application) application that is based on angular libraries.

Now you consider that we're going to have implement all of the our plugin views just in Main SPA application! for example every view in plugins maybe have some forms, models or inputs ... . but anything within there should be angular-based! and it increase client side complexity. in the other hands implementing some rules and helpers for plugins developers seems necessary to preventing irregularity.

my solution is customizing the `WebViewPage` and enrich it to have lots of helpers to provide angular elements and manage them. for example adding Angular helper which have own `BeginForm` method instead of `Html.BeginForm`, and it configures some attributed such as `ng-submit` and so on.

**Second** : Is there any better approach or existing better techniques to do it?